# Autoform-Wizard - How to change data dinamically between steps?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

im new in Meteor and i'm having a little step back. I'm using forwarder:autoform-wizard and i was following the example at github https://github.com/forwarder/meteor-wizard-example.

The example is very good, but i can't change the data dinamically, this is i'm trying to change what will appear in the next step of the wizard according to what was chosen before. Imagine that in the first step you have two choices drinks and snacks, and the person chooses drinks, then in the next step will appear another dropdown with choices relevant to drinks.

I've tried searching it, but all the solutions i've seen are only good for autoform and not wizard with autoform.

Thanks in advance.